# What does this mean: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]?

Tags: android, package-managers, android-package-managers

I try to deploy my app and sometimes get this error:

```
Failure 
[INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]
```

I tried to google it but don't find what the error means or what it's 
caused by. I deploy via IDE (IntelliJ) the file gets copied to the 
device to the /data/local/tmp (unrooted Huawei Ideos, running 2.2), 
but the package manager doesn't seem to like it. Before installing the 
apk, I already removed the app from the device beforehand. I also made 
sure there was no old file under /data/local/tmp on the device. Still 
I'm getting this error now. 
The package should be signed with the debug key, since I deploy via 
IDE by 'running' the app.

```
$ pwd 
/data/local/tmp 
$ ls -l 
-rw-rw-rw- shell    shell    17257686 2011-04-21 20:31 
com.company.shop 
$ pm install -r com.company.shop 
        pkg: com.company.shop 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]
```

What does it mean and how to resolve it?

**Edit/Update:**

I can avoid the error when not allowing the app to be installed on sdcard, setting

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

in the manifest. It's ok for development, but for production, it's not really what I want - since my app is quite large with 17mb; therefore I prefer it to be on sdcard.
How to ever be able to install it on the external memory without rooting (since this is the only way I could delete /mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec, which seems to be one solution as well).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can you install it by `pm install -f com.company.shop` ?

Comment: There are several variations on the `INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR` problem, for some of them see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30343659/313113

Comment: For me, it was as simple as the emulator "running out of space" (???) and i had to Wipe Data in the AVD Manager.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

remove this file from your device

```
/mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec
```

Edit/Update by Mathias Conradt (OP):

If you don't have root access, you need to mount the sdcard and remove it via pc:

```
/.android_secure/smdl2tmp1.asec
```

Comment: but my device is unrooted, and looking at the secure folder, only root has access. I was able to run the app before, only now since a while, cannot run it and it gives the above error.

Comment: btw - there's also a folder /mnt/asec/ that I can reach with non-root, but that's empty

Comment: Ok, turns out I need to mount the sdcard and remove it via pc (.android_secure/smdl2tmp1.asec), then it works again.

Comment: @Jazz This happend to me today. I would really like to know why/what this is about. Delete file manually? Why could not eclipse do this?
Is this a phone bug?

Comment: I couldn't find the .asec files in the mentioned locations, and erasing the sdcard from the emulator didn't work. It worked when I deleted the sdcard.img in my avd directory.

Comment: im having this problem. i cannot see the files/folders using my Mac. is there any other way?

Comment: This worked, but could you explain, why it does? What is in the mysterious smdl2tmp1.asec-file?

Comment: I can't find this file (on any path, even on the entire file system), even though the device is rooted. What else can I do?

Answer (score 224):

Change the install location from

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

into

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

in your project's AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: but i want to preferExternal...? How to fix this?

Comment: @AidenFry this is problem of eumlator problem. So change until you test on eumlator

Comment: @Sameer nope, this occurs on real devices too - but is inconsistent. Main ones are HTC Desire S and Nexus devices.

Comment: yeah, it happened with me on HTC Desire S, and fixed by changing install location to auto. Thanks..

Comment: @AidenFry Use user2445968 solution if you want to keep preferExternal.

Comment: For those who, like me, didn't have sources of the application, follow the instructions of this site : http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/ . apktool provide a very handful feature, decoding, modifying files, and recoding apk's.

Answer (score 32):

If you're using an emulator, edit it and add more memory.  I've had a problem just like this one and all I did was edit my AVD's memory from 200 MB to 1000 MB and the problem seem to go away...  Good Luck.

Comment: Yea it happened same with me. Thumbs up :)

Comment: In addition to increasing the memory I also had to wipe user data and only after that, the new size reflected and the error went away.

Comment: May I guess that you refer to Internal Storage, and not RAM?

Comment: I increased my AVD's memory, and then wiped data!! and now it's working.

Answer (score 7):

This means there was an earlier installation that was corrupt. If you install on external I would suggest that you format the sd card an try again.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this error repeatedly. I have found the simplest way to avoid the error in its entirety is to simply format the SD card. Using the phone or emulators internal tools. I have found that the automatically generated SD cards or even making your own sdcard.iso fails and causes this error unless formated by the internal android tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Resolved this with the same solution, as the problem is cause by an error writing to the SDCard, it is better than the workaorund of Rene f you want to keep android:installLocation="preferExternal".

Comment: Confirm. Error on SD was the reason for me. I tested it removing "prefer external" from manifest - its installed ok.

Answer (score 4):

For me this was caused by a lack of space on my emulator's SD card. I was working with a pretty large project and I had thought 40 mb was enough, but I changed it to 200 mb and the problem went away.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error with various `.apk` on Cyanogenmod 12.1 (Android 5.1.1) on my Note 8 with a second partition for Link2SD. I was able to install the apps by forcing the installation via adb as root:

```
adb root
adb install -f myapp.apk
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message from Android 5.0.1. 
I had changed the preferred install location to "Removable SD card" via Settings->Apps->Preferred Install Location.

I changed the option back to "Let the system decide" and the error message went away.

Comment: This seemed to be the solution for me running Cyanogenmod 12 (Android 5.0.2). That open seemed to be *forcing* the app to install on the removable SD card even though the app's manifest specified that it couldn't be installed there.

Answer (score 2):

It happens **when you don't have enough storage in internal storage** to install app. Just clear up some memory in internal storage by deleting unwanted files or photos. Memory cleaning software can also help.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the device language. I chnaged the language to Arabic to test my application. Then I got this error. Reverting back the language did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

android:installLocation="auto" works..!!

If Not,
Once check your external storage space size.[Available memory > app size]
If storage space is not enough then also this error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with emulator. It was gone when I changed emulator's CPU type from ARM to Intel.

Comment: This doesn't really help the OP with their problem, since their concern is getting it working on real world devices, plenty of which still use ARM CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

in some situations, removing the `libs/android-support-v4.jar` generates this error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, an uninstallation of several applications solved the problem. When a local storage has had enough memory, a deployment of APK completed successfully. But usually I simply restart a gadget, and installation completes.
Also, some programs like Clean Master may help. Simply often wipe unuseful processes and close programs with Clean Master and get enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my device fixed the issue for me.