# Android error activity manager type 3 (Eclipse, using jni)

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've been doing an app for a week in cocos2d-x (jni, in c++)

The problem is now I can't run it, can't test it on my device..

I get this error:

```
[2013-05-25 21:09:07 - PaperAgeAndroid] ------------------------------
[2013-05-25 21:09:07 - PaperAgeAndroid] Android Launch!
[2013-05-25 21:09:07 - PaperAgeAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-25 21:09:07 - PaperAgeAndroid] Performing es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid     activity launch
[2013-05-25 21:09:07 - PaperAgeAndroid] Uploading PaperAgeAndroid.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2013-05-25 21:09:44 - PaperAgeAndroid] Installing PaperAgeAndroid.apk...
[2013-05-25 21:09:48 - PaperAgeAndroid] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2013-05-25 21:09:48 - PaperAgeAndroid] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-05-25 21:09:48 - PaperAgeAndroid] Launch failed on device: 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:09:48 - PaperAgeAndroid] Starting activity es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:09:49 - PaperAgeAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=es.rks.paperage/.PaperAgeAndroid }
[2013-05-25 21:09:49 - PaperAgeAndroid] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-05-25 21:09:52 - PaperAgeAndroid] Starting activity es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:09:52 - PaperAgeAndroid] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-05-25 21:09:55 - PaperAgeAndroid] Starting activity es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:09:56 - PaperAgeAndroid] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-05-25 21:09:59 - PaperAgeAndroid] Starting activity es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:09:59 - PaperAgeAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=es.rks.paperage/.PaperAgeAndroid }
[2013-05-25 21:09:59 - PaperAgeAndroid] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2013-05-25 21:10:02 - PaperAgeAndroid] Starting activity es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2013-05-25 21:10:02 - PaperAgeAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=es.rks.paperage/.PaperAgeAndroid }
[2013-05-25 21:10:02 - PaperAgeAndroid] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2013-05-25 21:10:02 - PaperAgeAndroid] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {es.rks.paperage/es.rks.paperage.PaperAgeAndroid} does not exist.
```

I had this errors ago but deleting the app from my device fixed that :S Now I can't run the app

Yes, I have tried to clean the project and run it and I still have the same problem

My Android Manifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="es.rks.paperage"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">

        <activity android:name="PaperAgeAndroid"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"/>
</manifest>
```

I'm using Eclipse Juno on mac

This is the project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 1):

I am developing an Android app and faced the same problem. I use Eclipse as well. My problem was that someone had disabled the app from our test phone because it was still buggy, so I had to go to Settings->Apps->MyApp->Enable. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`, so you can try to add

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to your manifest.

Comment: Already done, now my error is

    Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE

Comment: Now INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744298/what-does-this-mean-failure-install-failed-container-error

Comment: My sd card is empty, I don't have the device rooted.

Now I have a fatal signal 11 (sigsev) at libc as I had couple days ago. I don't know how to see why is the error and almost all the things of stackoverflow I've tried don't work

Is a sh*t of Android that I can't know which damn line is causing that error

Comment: I fixed. It was that it was not finding a resource image (which path I select depending of the screen resolution)

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".App" android:enabled="false">
```

//.....

Change the value of android:enable="true" will work

Answer (score -1):

android:hasCode="false" 
         android:enabled="false"

im remove this code from manifest.

My project was modified