# Failure [install_failed_container_error] When trying to install a app using 'adb' command

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying install 'Subway Surfers' in Android sdk emulator.

But when I am installing the app using adb command after some time it displayed a error:

> 'Failure [install_failed_container_error]'

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: I trust there is a solution to your problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744298/what-does-this-mean-failure-install-failed-container-error

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase SD Card size on the emulator.
It won't probably go past install, emulator doesn't support OpenGL and the game will probably crash.