# I am getting Emulator Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

In order to overcome from this problem What I should do? Please help me.

Comment: Its occur at when I run emulator

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest, change this

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

to this

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Source : [What does this mean: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744298/what-does-this-mean-failure-install-failed-container-error)

"Change the install location from

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

into

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

in your project's AndroidManifest.xml.

this worked for me."